# Can we create local account users with a gmail address?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

We are using ADAL.Net to create users in Azure AD. using `SinginNames`, we can provide any email address (gmail or non-domain emails) as username to create Azure AD Local account.

when we try the same using Microsoft Graph (MSAL.Net), we are not able to create a user:

```
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: Property userPrincipalName is invalid.
```

How can we create gmail address as the username using Microsoft Graph or the Microsoft Graph Client Library?

*The newly created account should be local user account, not a guest user.*

```
var user = new User
{
    AccountEnabled = true,
    DisplayName = "displayName-value",
    MailNickname = "mailNickname-value",
    UserPrincipalName = "vetrivelmp1@gmail.com",
    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
    {
    ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true,
    Password = "Test123!@#"
    }
};

var graphClient = await _msGraphHelper.GetMsGraphClientAsync();
var createdUser = await graphClient
    .Users
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(user);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No You can not. You must have to request with [`tenant specific email`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs#http-request) following sample:

**Request URL:** https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

```
{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "KironTestDisplayName",
  "mailNickname": "KironTestNickName",
  "userPrincipalName": "KironTestingCreateUserWithMember@MyTenant.onmicrosoft.com",
  "userType":"guest",
  "passwordProfile" : {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
    "password": "Test@pass420"
  }
}
```

**Points to Remember:**

1. Get the proper token in which tenant you are going to create user
2. Need necessary [request permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs#permissions)
3. `userPrincipalName` should follow as
   `UserName@tenant-value.onmicrosoft.com`
4. "userType":"guest" Or "Member" You can add

> **Note:** Mail should be like `myUser@Mytenant.onmicrosoft.com` Other then you would encounter 400 request error like `Property userPrincipalName is invalid`

**Your Case:**

If you wanted to create user using `gmail account` then request pattern need to be changed You have to request for [invitation API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs) like below:

**Request Url:**  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations

**Request Body:**

```
{
  "invitedUserEmailAddress": "TestGmailUser@gmailUser",
  "inviteRedirectUrl": "https://myapp.com"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

> **Note:** If go to `azure portal` you would see you cannot add `gmail user` as domain member you add as guest user after invitation. So this
>   why you need above request pattern. Hope you are clear now.

**Gmail User Add SDK:**

```cs
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var invitation = new Invitation
{
    InvitedUserEmailAddress = "TestGmailUser@gmailUser",
    InviteRedirectUrl = "https://myapp.com"
};

await graphClient.Invitations
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(invitation);
```

**Azure Portal Verify:**

I have successfully added `gmail user` on my portal using above request. See the screen shot below:

[image]

Comment: On portal you can add as guest user, here as a domain user. For guest user gmail and other users can be added. Thanks

Comment: But when we use ad graph apis we can create any email address as AD user. but this is not allowed in MS Graph?

Comment: You can in that case you have to change your request pattern. See my example, I have given a sample for both `tenant user` and `gmail or other` user request example. Try  it out. Thanks and Happy coding!

Comment: when we invite a user, it is guest user only not a local account user. we need to allow gmail as local account user. if you use ad graph we can achieve the same. but when you use ms graph we cannot.

Comment: @Vetrivelmp You cannot add gmail user as local tenant user from portal so as to MS Graph. There is no other way which I have shown above.For [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs) I have given you the correct answer. And its very common personal account cannot be a tenant user. Its clearly written in [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs#permissions).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a good answer. I can create a new user via the AD B2C sign up process with whatever email, but when requesting via graph api, I get the above error. The issue must be something else and the response you've given is something completely different having to do with user invitations.

Comment: If I am not mistaken,  for addding tenant user you must follow the regulation with tenant domain name like this `UserName@tenant-value.onmicrosoft.com` but for other user you have to add them as guest user sending them invitation. And this answer was pointed to specific user scenario which was resolved, it might similer to your problem in that case would you kindly post your problem with relevant information so that our enginer could assist you there. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

For those still trying to accomplish this, the accepted answer here wasn't helpful, or at least is not the case here in 2021. I was able to create local B2C accounts with personal email addresses as well as custom sign in names using [Example 2: Create a user with social and local account identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-create-a-user-with-social-and-local-account-identities).

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
Content-type: application/json

{
  "displayName": "John Smith",
  "identities": [
    {
      "signInType": "userName",
      "issuer": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
      "issuerAssignedId": "johnsmith"
    },
    {
      "signInType": "emailAddress",
      "issuer": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
      "issuerAssignedId": "jsmith@yahoo.com"
    },
    {
      "signInType": "federated",
      "issuer": "facebook.com",
     "issuerAssignedId": "5eecb0cd"
    }
  ],
  "passwordProfile" : {
     "password": "password-value",
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false
  },
  "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration"
}
```